# Alphabetical Pagination in Rails 4.2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I'm currently trying to create an alphabetical pagination bar for a rails 4.2 application and I'm struggling to get it to work. I've found a few gems/plugins that are supposed to do this but they all seem to be incompatible with Rails 4 (or I'm too stupid to make them work, either way).

If anyone knows of any up-to-date gems that can do this, or can point me in the right direction to get started I'd really appreciate it.

EDIT: The words are in the database file and are extracted + sorted alphabetically by the below code. I'm wondering how to set up the pagination (by letter).

The information I want to paginate is a list of words in a dictionary drawn from a mysql database using the following code:

Controller:

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_word, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@words = Word.all
end

def show
end

private
 def set_word
  @word = Word.find(params[:id])
 end

def word_params
  params.require(:word).permit(:word, :wordtype, :description)
end
end
```

View:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Words</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Word</th>
      <th>Wordtype</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @words.each do |word| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= word.word %></td>
        <td><%= word.wordtype %></td>
        <td><%= word.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', word %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm unclear what you want.  You want words sorted alphabetically (which I don't see in your code) and you also want pagination by N amount or by letter?

Comment: The words are in the database file and are extracted + sorted alphabetically by the above code. I'm wondering how to set up the pagination (by letter). I'll add this to my question.